# How do you solve the issue with an object with subdivision and multiple materials on it?

Tags: materials, geometry, subdivision-surface

I was making a charger and I have given it some subdivision as usual. Now one side of the charger has a bit different texture (less glossier to be specific) so I tried that in blender, but that material looks shrunk.

[image: object]

I have faced this problem earlier also but that was an object with higher geometry. So I used inset and extrude tools to solve that. But here I cannot do that as it is only 1 large face.

This is what my geometry looks like, with the face selected that I want to edit.

[image: edit mode]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two solutions:

- create 4 additional edge loops close to your first edges so that it forces your texture to stick to these edges

or

- unwrap your object and use a black square as a factor in a mix shader

[image]